# AndroidManifest.xml does not merge activity info upon Build

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Pretty new to Mono for Android (C#), and I'm seeming to have trouble during one of their [tutorials](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/Hello_Multiscreen_Applications) where it mentions that info on Activities is merged into AndroidManifest.xml upon compilation.

The FirstActivity class is set to Compile upon Build, yet no AndroidManifest file is created. One can be created via the Project menu but it doesn't include any information on Activities and does not update when these are changed.

Had a look around on the internet but I only managed to find issues relating to Visual Studio.

Any help would be appreciated! :) Thanks.

edit: I'm using the evaluation version right now, if that's any problem.

edit: Getting more problems it seems. Had trouble accessing the AVD through Mono and decided to reinstall the Android SDK to the latest version. Attempts to run the program on the emulator cause the 'Devices' list to disappear shortly after emulator startup (or, at the very best, it fails to acknowledge that an emulator is active). running 'adb devices' spits out the correct emulator "emulator-5554" or something, but Mono's just repeatedly failing to notice.

It's correctly pointed to Android SDK and Java as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AndroidManifest.xml that is generated is created in:

`obj\Debug\android\AndroidManifest.xml`

The one in your project is not touched.

Comment: Can't believe I let that slip. It doesn't show up in the Solution window so naturally I didn't look for it. Thank you! Do you know why the latter problem (concerning AVD target) is occurring and how to fix it?